# How to turn on chat rating in Zendesk Chat UI? (ZDCChat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, zendesk, zopim

I don't know how to turn on chat rating after chat ends in Zendesk Chat UI. I can see rating cell in code (ZDCRatingCell), rating methods, but I can't find parameter which will change default behaviour to show chat rating (like it works in turning on/off email transcriptions). I don't want to write custom code to solve this issue, I would rather use default Zendesk solution.

Comment: this might help https://chat.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212016608-Measuring-visitor-satisfaction-with-chat-rating#topic_ndr_fwx_kq

Comment: it helped. The missing piece was the fact, that the rating funcitonality is not automatic. The operator on company side have to activate it.